# Broadcast receiver not getting called after setting alarm using AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

This is my ScreenStateReceiver(a BroadcastReceiver)  which receives the broadcast whenever the screen goes off and whenever the screen comes back online.

```
public class ScreenStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
        Log.e("ScreenStateReceiver", "Screen Intent Action On " + intent.getAction());
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.e("ScreenStateReceiver", "Screen Intent Action Off" + intent.getAction());
            setAlarm(context);
        }
    }

    private void setAlarm(Context context){

        Intent in  = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
        in.setAction("screen_off");
        PendingIntent sender =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 161, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            am.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 1000L, sender);
        else
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() +  60 * 1000L, sender);
    }
}
```

Now my receiver for the alarm set by AlarmManager is :

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("AlarmReciever", "Alarm goes off");
    }
}
```

Now I have registered both the receivers in my MainActivity like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScreenStateReceiver screenStateReceiver = new ScreenStateReceiver();
        IntentFilter in = new IntentFilter();
        in.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        in.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

        this.registerReceiver(screenStateReceiver, in);

        AlarmReciever alarmReciever = new AlarmReciever();
        in = new IntentFilter();
        in.addAction("screen_off");

        this.registerReceiver(alarmReciever, in);
    }
}
```

Now I am having a hard time since the logs I have printed in AlarmReceiver, it is never getting printed that is, AlarmReceiver is never getting called when the screen goes off. Can anybody help me this?

Comment: For an `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` alarm, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is _waaay_ in the future. Use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` to figure the alarm time instead. Or change the alarm to an `RTC` type.

Comment: I tried it with RTC_WAKEUP, it is not working. Is setting an alarm from inside a BroadcastReceiver is a problem? Or alarm just doesn't go off when the screen is off? Do you have an idea about that?

Comment: @MikeM.     One more thing if I register my receiver in the manifest, it works but If i do it in my activity, it does not. Why is that so?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I missed that. Explicit `Intent`s - i.e., those that target a specific class - don't work with dynamically registered Receivers. If you want it to work with the Receiver registered on the `Activity`, change the alarm `Intent` to `Intent in  = new Intent("screen_off");`, which is an implicit `Intent`. The alarm times and types look OK now.

Comment: @MikeM. Perfect...It worked..Thanks a lot Mike